# ASP.NET posting data to payment service with HttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, httphandler, payment-processing

I'm trying to post some data to a payment service and render the response back through and `HttpHandler`. The response is a form the user fill out to make their payment. It's a web forms app, so I can't use multiple forms (I know you can in general, but the existing code I'm working on is making it hard. I just have a link to the handler with a order id in the querystring.

I'm not even sure that what I'm trying to do here is a good idea or will even work out. If you have a better idea please let me know. Here is the code I have so far:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace Web
{
    public class Begin_invoice : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var orderNumber = context.Request.QueryString["invoice-numer"];

            //todo: get some extra data from local service here

            var URI = "https://somepaymetservice/start.action";

            var data = new StringBuilder();

            data.Append("merchant=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("666111") + "&");
            data.Append("amount=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("1") + "&");
            data.Append("lang=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("sv") + "&");
            data.Append("currency=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("752") + "&");
            data.Append("orderid=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(orderNumber) + "&");
            data.Append("accepturl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://localhost:50113/Complete-invoice.ashx") + "&");
            data.Append("test=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("1") + "&");

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                var response = client.UploadString(URI, data.ToString());

                context.Response.Write(response);
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

The obvious first problem is all the resources for the payment page. Urls to resources are relative so they won't get downloaded. Is there some library or other feature that can take care of this proxy stuff, can I use some location header or something like that? All suggestions are appreciated?

Comment: I have a nagging suspicion that you're on the wrong track here. Does the provider not offer documentation and samples? Which provider is it?

Comment: It's called dibs.se, all I'm doing is posting some data to a form on a page hosted on dibs.se. If I could use a regular html form on my end it would all be super easy. I have an existing page (not done by me) with a list of unpaid invoices. I was hoping I could just add a simple "pay invoice"-link to every row. Since all existing data lives within form required by asp.net webforms. But I agree this doesent feel like the right way.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://tech.dibspayment.com/10_step_guide/choose_your_method_of_authorization/ Method 1 looks easier. I notice also that in the downloads area - which I don't have access to - they offer ASP.NET examples and, if you want to go with method 2, a .NET DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was forced to refactor my markup to allow multiple forms on a page. Once that was done the DIBS api was really easy to use.